# Google Developer Console shows 0 supported devices

Tags: android, xml, libgdx, live-wallpaper, google-console-developer

I want to publish my app on Google Play but when I upload my .apk file, it shows that it is supported by 0 devices. I know that there is already a few topics about this but I have not find solution in any of them. Below I am attaching source-code of my android manifest. I also would like to mention that I am using LibGDX for this application and it is an Android Live Wallpaper. Also everything works fine on test devices and emulator. Thanks for your answers.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.caller.generationslwp.android"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0.1" >

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
        <uses-feature android:name ="android:software.live_wallpaper" android:required="true"></uses-feature>
        <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"></uses-feature>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="true"></uses-feature>



        <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                          android:smallScreens="true"
                          android:normalScreens="true"
                          android:largeScreens="true"
                          android:xlargeScreens="true"
                          android:anyDensity="true"
        />



        <application
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"

        >
            <service android:name =".LiveWallpaperAndroid"
             android:label = "@string/app_name"
             android:icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher"
             android:permission = "android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
                </intent-filter>
                <meta-data android:name ="android.service.wallpaper"
                 android:resource ="@xml/livewallpaper" />
            </service>


            <activity
                android:name="com.caller.generationslwp.android.Settings"
                android:exported="true"
                android:label="@string/preview_app_name">


            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest

>
```

Comment: i couldn't detect something wrong in this code : what is the size of your apk is it bigger than 50MB ?

Comment: No, it is only about 4 MB, can't be something importat missing in manifest? Or can't be the problem with Libgdx libraries? They use Gradle for generating project and I am not much skilled with it, so can't something with gradle be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found where the problem was. It was a typo `android:software.live_wallpaper`, it should be `android.software.live_wallpaper`. Now it shows over 9 000 supported devices.

Comment: It's really weird. I think it's because of different gradle version that might be root cause of problem. I successfully use `android:software...` for gradle 2.x, but not succeeded for gradle 3.x. Now used your solution, it works.