# 0 support device at Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play

I have a problem on Android apps...
It runs perfect on my device, but support will be 0 on developer console.

This will be my AndroidManifest.xml.
I checked that it has no error.

I have no idea where to look.

Could someone help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="xxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<permission
    android:name="xxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="xxx"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ProfileCropImageActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="xxx.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="xxx.services.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="xxx.services.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="xxx.services.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
</application>
```

following is the part of `build.gradle`:

```
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: What is your target SDK?

Comment: please add build.gradle

Comment: target SDK will be 23 I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33786436/google-developer-console-shows-0-supported-devices) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020237/android-app-is-supported-by-0-devices), I think it can help you solve your problem.
But to summarize, it might be caused by incorrect naming in either your uses permission or uses feature. It also might be caused by a third party library that you have used. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the links! I removed the "compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.codec:1.8'" line and it worked!

Comment: Nice! Glad it helped!